# How to pass 'this' as parameter in click event in script DOM to any function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Actually I was struggling with passing`this` as parameter to any function defined under onclick event handler ..Here's the code in which I need to pass `this`

```
<button  class="btn btn-default buttonattr"style="font-family:Pangolin"   onclick="myhit(\''+this["post"]+'\',\''+this["love"]+'\', ** here this as parameter**);myclick()"><span  class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart fa-lg "></span> Love</button>
```

Hoping for a positive reply.

Comment: Actually this is inside script ,so this button line is like html+=//html given in question

Comment: Have you tried fixing the punctuation marks?

Comment: The answer is simple, **don't use inline javascript** !

Comment: simpler: pass `this` and pluck props in the handler: `onclick="myhit(this);myclick()"`

Comment: NO matter what I need to use inline javascript

Comment: You're mistaken, you ***never*** have to use inline javascript, and you shouldn't !

Comment: Maybe you could tell us where `this["post"]` and `this["love"]` is coming from, what is `this` supposed to be here, and why would it have those properties ?

Comment: inline js isn't the worst thing in the world, and in some CMSs or other systems, it's the only reasonable option.

Comment: What is `this` anyway.... I think you need to show more context. Looks like you are doing string concatenation to build innerHTML, but you do not show it in full.

Comment: ok wait I will show

Comment: I want `this` so that I can know that this button was the one clicked out of many buttons

Answer (score 0):

You need `this` inside your function? Meaning the button that was clicked on?

First do this in your html:

`onclick="myhit(ev);myclick();"`

In your `myhit()` method:

```
var myhit = function (ev) {
    var el = ev.target;
    //now el is the button that was clicked to fire this method
};
```

Comment: like even if I use inline javascript this would work

Answer (score 0):

This is the code:

```js
function MyFunction(_this)
   {
    console.log($(_this).val());
    console.log($(_this).attr("class"));
   }
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>

<input type="button" onclick="MyFunction(this)" value="Click Me!!" class="my-class"/>
```

Comment: How to pass it 'this' using inline javascript